# Using gravatar in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My rails app is currently using the 'gravtastic' gem which allows me to use the following:

```
<%= image_tag current_user.gravatar_url %>
```

I have created a model called clients which allows you to enter a 'name', 'email', etc.. What I am trying to do is use the 'email' field and display their gravitar on the 'show' view. Currently I use the following to display the client's email:

```
<%= @client.email %>
```

Thanks and I hope I explained this good enough.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What I am trying to do is use the 'email' field and display their gravitar on the 'show' view. This way I can show the gravitar of each client.

Comment: What problem do you have? Does you code raise an exception?

Comment: No, I don't know what code to use to generate this result. The client model is not a user so I can't use the current_user tag.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [documentation](https://github.com/chrislloyd/gravtastic#usage) the just two steps need to be done:

1) Add `Gravtastic` to your `Client`model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Gravtastic
  gravtastic

  # ...
end
```

2) Use the generated `gravatar_url` in your view:

```
<%= image_tag(@client.gravatar_url) %>
```